# how to make alertdialog show with listview?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-alertdialog

i want to show alertdialog when i click on a listview on my activity, i have a code to show the alertdialog but i know something wrong with my code and i dont know how to fix it, the alert didn't show like what i want.
here's my code :

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    new bike_type_dao(responsetype).view_bike_type();


    final Entity_Brand brand = adapterBrand.getItem(position);


    builder = new Dialog(this);
    builder.setTitle(brand.getBrand_name());
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.tab_brand_activity, null, false);
    builder.setContentView(view);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    listtype = (ListView) builder.findViewById(R.id.list_sepeda);
    listtype.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);
    listtype.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Entity_Bike_Type>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList));
    listtype.showContextMenu();


    builder.show();

}
```

i hope someone can help me with this problem. thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your activity extends `ListActivity` (otherwise it wouldn't have the `onListItemClick` method to override in the first place.

According to the API documentation, when an item in your listView is clicked, `onListItemClick` gets called.  At this point, you're also setting your activity as an `OnItemClickListener`, which means you're defining the method `OnItemClick` somewhere in this activity as well.  You could just take that code and put it in `onListItemClick` since it would be doing the same thing.

As for the `alertDialog` you want to show, I usually just stick to using `AlertDialog.Builder` to make & show simple alertDialogs. It works and it's probably simpler than working with the `Dialog` class directly.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(brand.getBrand_name());
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.show();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i've doing what you told, but it's still not work, the alert still not show.

Comment: Then my guess is that somehow `onListItemClick` might not be called.  You could try to add a simple Log message in there and look at LogCat to see if it is being called: e.g.: `Log.d("List Item", "List item has been clicked")`  Otherwise, you can also try calling  `setOnItemClickListener` to your listView in `onCreate` and put all the code you want the method `onListItemClick` (you'll need to have your activity implement `OnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm let me clarify something, do you want to show a alert dialog when you click the whole list view not the items in it?.. if so, i think you should implement the onclick listener not the onitemclick listenerm though i never tried implementing alert dialog on click of a listview but i think this should do it

Comment: i've change like you said, onitemclick i've replace with listtype.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this); but it's not work to, i've check on DDMS,, the app get what i want to show, but alertdialog is not showing,,it's force close.